# VueJS Reactive element set one item to true all others false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am working on a VueJS application with the composition API.
I have setup a reactive element as such

```
const sections = reactive({
  section1: true,
  section2: false,
  section3: false,
  section4: false,
  section5: false,
  section6: false
})
```

As each button on the page is clicked, I want to show and hide the various elements (any many other actions) based on their Boolean value.
I can certainly make a function for each button that will set everything individually as you see in this code

```
const section1Button= () => {
  sections.section1 = true,
  sections.section2 = false,
  sections.section3 = false,
  sections.section4 = false,
  sections.section5 = false,
  sections.section6 = false
}
const section2Button= () => {
  sections.section1 = false,
  sections.section2 = true,
  sections.section3 = false,
  sections.section4 = false,
  sections.section5 = false,
  sections.section6 = false
}
```

This absolutely works, but it means I have to make multiple functions that essentially have 1 change.
Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?
I feel like I should be able to do this with a loop or an If statement, but it just isn't coming to me.
This is my first post to stackoverflow, so if I did not provide enough detail, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Object.entries` to loop over key/values pairs of `sections` and set `true`/`false` accordingly, creating a new `sections` object:

```
const updateSections = (section) => {
  sections = Object.entries(sections).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    // if key matches selected section, set to true
    if (key === section) return { ...acc, [key]: true };
    // otherwise set to false
    return { ...acc, [key]: false };
  }, {});
}

// trigger updateSections for a particular section however you want
v-on:click="updateSections('section1')"
```

If you find you need to directly modify the properties, you can instead use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
const updateSections = (section) => {
  Object.keys(sections).forEach(key => {
    // if key matches selected section, set to true
    if (key === section) sections[key] = true;
    // otherwise set to false
    sections[key] = false;
  });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!